# chartjs chart.update() function not rendering lines in foreground

Tags: chart.js

I have a core psychrometric chart rendered in the background. Then, I plot the process lines in blue over the top of the background scatter chart; as shown below:

[image]

I call the background chart first and then plot the state lines using the `chart.update()` function.  However, my background chart is chopping up my state lines (the blue lines).

How do I make the lines created with the `chart.update()` function reside in the foreground such that it isn't chopped up by the lines in the background?

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out.  I was using the example documentation for the update.chart() method which shows:

```js
function addData(chart, data) {
    chart.data.datasets.forEach((dataset) => {
        dataset.data.push(data);
    });
    chart.update();
}
```

However, chartjs renders to the foreground the data that is declared first in the array.  So, to make the data thats inserted into the chart using the chart.update() method, I replaced the push() method with an unshift() method.  For example:

```js
function addData(chart, data) {
    chart.data.datasets.forEach((dataset) => {
        dataset.data.unshift(data);
    });
    chart.update();
}
```